# Crossplatform library to normalize audio?

Tags: c++, audio

Do you know any cross-platform audio library I can use to normalize sampled audio?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Google is your friend:

http://normalize.nongnu.org/

https://neon1.net/prog/normalizer.html

If you can't use GPL code in your project, then just read the description of the algorithm on the second website and implement your own. It's pretty simple.

Answer (score 1):

normalization is an easy process. this is a simple implementation for `float`s:

```
float peakAmplitude(0.0f);

/* find the peak */
for (size_t idx(0); idx < bufferLength; ++idx) {
    peakAmplitude = std::max(peakAmplitude, std::fabs(buffer[idx]));
}

if (0.0f >= peakAmplitude) {
    std::cout << "signal is silent\n";
    return;
}

/* apply normalization */
const float mul(1.0f / peakAmplitude);
for (size_t idx(0); idx < bufferLength; ++idx) {
    buffer[idx] *= mul;
}
```

other signal formats can be easily converted.

Comment: Well, its simple, unless you want to normalize *perceptual* loudness.

Comment: @derobert an rms normalization implementation in the above written style requires *one* more line of code.

Comment: That's true, but that's not perceptual loudness. They human auditory system doesn't hear all frequencies equally, so perceptual loudness is much harder. See, e.g., http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Perceived_Human_Hearing.png

Comment: if you think the OP needs clarification, feel free to ask the OP for it. in my camp, peak normalization is the default, so that is how i answered.